# unable to edit sonata media field in front end

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-media-bundle

Hi i added a sonata media field to sonata user entity in one-to-one relation as :

```
<one-to-one field="icons" target-entity="AppBundle\Entity\Media\Media">
<join-column name="icons_id" referenced-column-name="id" on-delete="CASCADE" on-update="CASCADE"/>
```

i overrited Profile form Type and i'm able to edit all user fields from Profile page But when i try to edit media file 
It doesnt work without showing any error message.

**PS**: From back office it works properly.

Does anyone have an idea about editing sonata media field in frontEnd please ?
Thanks